# Batch timed loop php files

Tags: php, jquery, json, batch-file, timer

How do you create a .bat file that runs a file every hour?
eg.

I want 'php_json.php' to run every hour (60 min) to collect new data.
I heard that this was possible with batch-files.

This .bat file will be uploaded to a SQL server, and will not be able to run on a local machine.

Comment: Your best bet is probably just a scheduled task to be honest.

Comment: Yeah, but I want it to run on a SQL server.

Comment: Your SQL server will run under windows, probably some server edition, which means it supports scheduled tasks as well, Of course, you'll have to install PHP on it if you want to execute a php file.

Comment: I was in contact with my server-provider. they cannot allow me to do this for some odd reason. I'm using one.com as a provider.

Comment: If your host doesn't allow you to run commands like npocmaka's post suggests doing, does your host provide any CRON facility? If it does I'll write you an answer based around that, if not there are alternatives I can write up a guide for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

:loop_label
C:\PHP5\php.exe -f "c:\php_json.php"
PING -n 3600 127.0.0.1 >NUL 2>&1
goto :loop_label
```

?